# How can I choose a time zone?

Tags: release-juno, settings, release-hera

I would like to to set the local time. Where is rcS or the file that contains UTC parameters?

Comment: While installing the eOS or after the installation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want elementary to use localtime instead of UTC to avoid time differences when dualbooting elementary and Windows.

Just execute on terminal: `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock`

You can check if that's working with the command `timedatectl` (may need to reboot).

---

[Source](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/time-differences-ubuntu-1604-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you'd like to be able to set the timezone? You can set the timezone from **System Settings** → **Date & Time** → **Time Zone**. Choosing a timezone there will set the correct offset from UTC.